# Removing a delegate computer for use with CredSSP

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have CREDSSP client enabled on my desktop to allow a double-hop remoting to a number of servers. Some of those servers have now been decommisioned, so my question is how do I remove those specific delegates without disabling and reenabling CREDSSP which is what I have done up until now?

E.g to add an additional delegate I can do:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer "mynewserver.mydomain.local"
```

so I want to be able to do something like:

```
Remove-WSMANCredSSPDelegate -DelegateComputer "mynewserver.mydomain.local"
```

but all I can do is

```
Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) might be a better place for it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I agree it is not traditional programming, however it is a question about how to do something in a scripting language that there is a tag for on SO. The solution will be a code solution

Answer (score 1):

The settings for delegate computers are kept in the registry under HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentials

I tried directly modifying these values but found while they could be removed it did not take effect.  Fortunately using the registry values you can compare the existing values against the ones you wish to keep vs remove and disable/re-enable.

Here's an example, should be easy to convert to a cmdlet if desired:

```
$remove = 'COMPUTER-TO-REMOVE'

$item = Get-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentials'

$keep = $item | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Property' `
    | ForEach-Object { $item.GetValue($_).TrimStart('wsman/') } `
    | Where-Object { $_ -ne $remove }

Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client
if ($keep) {
    Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer $keep -Force 1>$null
}
```

Comment: This looks promising - I will give it a go and mark as the answer if successful. As this is a registry edit, do you know if it requires a reboot to be effective?

Comment: It's not a registry edit per se but rather I'm reading the registry in order to build a difference list in order to selectively enable the computers in the list I don't want to remove.  The Enable/Disable-WSManCredSSP commands do not require a reboot.

Answer (score -2):

```
Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
```

and

```
Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client
```

= all clean

Comment: I have down voted because as I stated in my question, I already do this. I asked the question to establish a neater/more intelligent way of removing defunct server, without disabling and reenabling CredSSP as that seems to me to be overkill.